# Many instances of java.time.ZoneRegion in Java heap. Isn't ZoneId instances supposed to be cached?

Tags: java, zoneid

I have a lot of objects that have `ZoneId tz` field.
All instances of `tz` field are created via `ZoneId.of` static method.
My initial choice for `ZoneId` instead of plain `String` was the expectation that `ZoneId` instances would be cached (as there is a limited set of timezones). However, after analyzing the heap I found that is not true:

[image]

Every call to `ZoneId.of` with the same parameter creates a new instance of `ZoneRegion`:

```
ZoneId zoneId1 = ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev"); //allocates new ZoneRegion
ZoneId zoneId2 = ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev"); //allocates new ZoneRegion
```

My question is - is that expected or this is some kind of JVM bug?

```
openjdk version "21.0.1" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.1+12-Ubuntu-222.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.1+12-Ubuntu-222.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Where does it say that `ZoneId` will be cached?

Comment: When you perform a lot of `ZoneId.of(String)` calls, you didn’t chose “*for ZoneId instead of plain String*” but are still using `String`. Choosing `ZoneId` implies passing around `ZoneId` instances, eliminating the necessity to repeatedly call `ZoneId.of(String)`. Besides that, `ZoneId`’s documentation says that it is a [value-based class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) so you shouldn’t make assumptions about object identities at all. They might be cached or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is - is that expected or this is some kind of JVM bug?

Checking the most recent javadoc (JDK22u), 'these values are singletons' is mentioned nowhere. Because we can state your case a lot simpler without bringing heap issues into it:

```
// bug claim:
ZoneId a = ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev");
ZoneId b = ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev");
System.out.println(a == b); // should print true!
```

... but this prints `false`, and that therefore implies the mechanisms powering `ZoneId.of` **do not** lead to singleton `ZoneId` objects - either the JDK doesn't exist with every possible ZoneId object pre-cached, or, ZoneId.of itself fails to establish a cache.

> or this is some kind of JVM bug?

Well, the Java Lang Spec and Java Virtual Machine Spec aren't going to (or should not) mention anything about this, as it's not in the `java.lang` package or sub-package, which is where any types that are so crucial to the language itself, they need mentioning in the JLS/JVMS go.

Thus, the javadoc is the canonical source of the specification.

**`ZoneId` does not mention that they are singletons anywhere in the javadoc, nor does `ZoneId.of` mention this.**

For reference, [current JDK22u sources of ZoneId](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk22u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/ZoneId.java).

There is the line:

```
 * The ID is unique within the system.
```

On ZoneId itself which one *might* interpret as: "ID" here is short for "an instance of ZoneId", but that's not a slamdunk obvious interpretation of that line; what they are talking about is that e.g. `Europe/Kiev` as a concept cannot lead to two different notions of what timezone that refers to at the same time. This part of the docs isn't about the implementation detail level notion of '... and the system shall cache this notion so that no two instances need to exist'.

It **does** contain a rider that instances are to be treated as ValueBased (at the end of the main javadoc): You should not make an assumption either way on what e.g. `==` would do (in other words, they are explicitly reserving the right to introduce some sort of caching mechanism, or that these will become straight up valhalla style value classes that don't *have* an identity in the first place). But that simply stipulates you shouldn't rely on **either**: You cannot rely on repeated calls to `ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev")` returning different objects, **nor** can you rely on such calls returning the same object. Code-wise you shouldn't be thinking of ZoneId instances of objects at all.

### A solution

If your profiler report strongly suggests that reducing the number of ZoneId instances is going to help, then, the API doc gives you the right to cache these:

```
private static final Map<String, ZoneId> CACHED_ZONE_IDS = new HashMap<>();

public static ZoneId cachedOf(String id) {
  return CACHED_ZONE_IDS.computeIfAbsent(id, ZoneId::of);
}
```

If you're worried about needing to 'time out' ZoneIds no longer in active use from your cached map, you could look into guava's CacheBuilder, but that seems like overkill here; I'd just leave it as those 3 short lines of code above.